# PHP How to organize array into groups but keep the order?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make arrays into groups by **`id`**,
but still keep the orders, that means it might have duplicate groups, 
like:

```
Group1 [id: 1]
Group2 [id: 2]
Group3 [id: 1]
....
...
..
.
```

Array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'message' => 'AAA',
    'sent_on' => 1582097767
  ),

  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'message' => 'AAAQAW',
    'sent_on' => 1582097770
  ),

  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'message' => 'dqwdq',
    'sent_on' => 1582097772
  ),

  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'message' => 'dqwdq',
    'sent_on' => 1582097773
  ),

  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'message' => 'wq',
    'sent_on' => 1582097773
  ),

  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'message' => 'd',
    'sent_on' => 1582097774
  ),

  6 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'message' => 'dew',
    'sent_on' => 1582112219
  )
)
```

**Hoped result:**

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 1,
          'message' => 'AAA',
          'sent_on' => 1582097767

        ),
    ),

    1 => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 2,
          'message' => 'AAAQAW',
          'sent_on' => 1582097770

        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'id' => 2,
          'message' => 'dqwdq',
          'sent_on' => 1582097772

        )
    ),

    2 => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 1,
          'message' => 'dqwdq',
          'sent_on' => 1582097773

        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'id' => 1,
          'message' => 'wq',
          'sent_on' => 1582097773

        )
    ),

    3 => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 2,
          'message' => 'd',
          'sent_on' => 1582097774

        )
    ),

    4 => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 1,
          'message' => 'dew',
          'sent_on' => 1582112219

        )
    )
)
```

Comment: aaaand what seems to be an issue?

Comment: @matiit Uh, yes, I only know how to make the array into only two groups like `id=1`, `id=2`, but in my hope it need to have five groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it could be done pretty easy by using `array_reduce`:

```
$lastCheckedItem = ['id' => 0];

$finalArray = array_reduce($array, static function(array $carry, array $item) use (&$lastCheckedItem) {
    if ($lastCheckedItem['id'] === $item['id'] && !empty($carry)) {
        $lastKey = array_key_last($carry);
        $carry[$lastKey][] = $item;
    }
    else {
        $carry[] = [$item];
    }

    $lastCheckedItem = $item;

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Great answer !! By the way, why the array name is `$carry` lol

Comment: yw. Well, because it carries the values set on each iteration until the loop is ended.

Comment: Got it. It made me laugh due to it is my english nickname from my dad.

Comment: yeah.. I noticed it since you asked about it :)